# how should i construct filters for multiple request parameters in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm newbie Flask,SQLAlchemy and trying to develop application using flask-sqlalchemy.

search web from that accept 2 request paratemer,firstname and lastname. Most primitive way to construct search condition will be like this. if request parameters is not empty, multiple filters.

```
def search():
   rs = User.query      
   if not request.arg.get('firstname'):
         rs = rs.filter(User.firstname=requst.arg.get('firstname'))
   if not requst.arg.get('lastname'):
         rs = rs.filter(User.lastname=requst.arg.get('lastname'))
   rs.all()
```

Don't want do that. if query filter could invalidate when request parameters is empty string, query will be fixed in this way. I hope to do so.

```
   rs = User.query.\
        filter(User.firstname=requst.arg.get('firstname')).\
        filter(User.lastname=requst.arg.get('lastname')).\
        all()
```

How should I construct filters with multiple request parameters?